# Is there a command-line tool to convert Postgre's SQL codes to MySQL ones?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I need to migrate some databases from PostgreSQL to MySQL. There is the MySQL Workbench that can do that, but I need to automatize this task under a Debian-like Operating System without a GUI.

Currently, there is no way to connect that database servers directly. I need to export a SQL file from one to import in another.

I created a simple `parser` to do that, but with limited application and test cases. Tools that require a GUI is not useful in this moment. My parser is available [here](https://gist.github.com/lucasvenez/258635be08c643d287c2c48d01939ac8). I used just 1h30m to create that.

There is some command line tool that already converts Postgre's SQL codes to MySQL ones?

Comment: PostgreSQL uses the standard conforming SQLSTATE as error number. You should stick with that if you want to write portable code. I am sure there is a way to get SQLSTATEs from MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz Albe. It is an important information. Do you know some parse between Postgre's SQL and MySQL one?